# charts loading problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when we create charts in asp.net mvc is it necessary to use chart control?
and if yes then at the time of deployment is it necessary to install chart control?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4, the charting controls are now built-in. There's some info on Scott Guthrie's blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

This will not require any additional installation when you deploy to the server (assuming it also supports .NET 4).

If you are using .NET 3.5, then you will need to install the charting controls on your developer machine, however I can't find any solid info on whether you need to install the charts on the server, or if they'll just be included in the bin folder and run from there (I would have hoped so, but often things need installing on the server for no reason ;-))

Comment: If you are using MVC 3, there is also the new `ChartHelper`. It's a pretty simplistic wrapper around the chart control, but if it meets your needs it's much easier to work with.